# Inequality concept problem

Tags: inequality

Hello I am a student and had the following problems in inequality:
$-2\le 1 $
Squaring both sides the sign changes 
$4\gt 1$
But for 
$-1\lt 1$
Squaring the terms we get 
$1\le 1$
I am stuck here please help me to understand this concept

Comment: What is your question? Please take the time to review your question (fix grammatical errors, etc)

Comment: Please use mathjax too

Comment: I am new to stack exchange so I don't know much about mathjax will surely do next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have committed a serious error.  In inequalities like $a<b$, you can only multiply both sides by the same number, and you cannot square both sides.  In addition, you have to change the multiplication sign if you multiply a negative number.  T square both sides, it only holds for inequalities like $|a|<|b|$.

Comment: please mark the tick @ShantanuKaushik

Comment: @XcoderX Shouldn't the number to be multiplied be a positive number.  Because multiplying by a negative number will result in reversing the inequality sign. By the way you seem to be in a hurry for your 1k. Let the OP give a time to understand the concept. He will surely tick the mark after he likes your answer.  No offense.  :-)

Comment: Does the same thing happens if we have modulus of a complex number on one side and a real number on other side??

Comment: You cannot modulus a complex number.  Also @Manthanein, no, I have already gotten 1000 on other sites already

Comment: @XcoderX I already saw your answers on Physics stackexchange. My friend that was a very bad joke by me but you took it seriously.  You have the true qualities of a math lover.  Because math is all about seriousness with a blend of fun throughout.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality signs don't remain the same if one of the sides is negative. 
But the inequality sign can remain the same even after squaring if the absolute value i.e. the magnitude of the numbers on either side of inequality sign follows the sign of inequality.

I hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: You could mention about modulus too

Comment: @XcoderX I could've spoke about it but the word "magnitude" simply is a lucid word to explain the phenomenon and I didn't want the OP to get confused with modulus of complex numbers (as he already did)